# Is there a method or a way that can constraining eager loading and nested eager loading at the same time?

Tags: laravel

We can use [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) like:

```
$users = App\User::with(['author' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('isActive', '1');
}])->get();
```

And we can use [Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) like:

```
$books = App\Book::with('author.books')->get();
```

But is there a way to use them both at the same time. I mean in the example above eager load with authors that are active and with eager loading books of the author at the same time? Is there a method or a way for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok just trying something bald here. Never tested. Maybe it works, maybe not.

What if you actually nested the eager loading like this

```
$users = App\User::with(['author' => function ($query) {
    $query->with(['books' => function ($subquery) {
        $subquery->where('isActive', 1);
    }])->where('isActive', '1');
}])->get();
```

Comment: your example returns all users regardless of the conditions. Actually will try something according to your example.

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to return all users. If you want only users that have books you use `whereHas()` or `has()`.

Comment: yes actually you are right. but why are you using 'isActive', 1 twice.

Comment: What about something like this? $users = App\User::with(['author' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('isActive', '1')->with('books');
}])->get();

Comment: @Skeletor lol. isActive is just a random attribute. In the example, Im saying where the book is active and where the author is active. But you can totally replace isActive by any other column you want. same thing. So yeah, just `with('books')` would still get the job done.

Comment: All right then @EddyTheDove I got it and it works great ;)